# How can I make a tibble/tbl_df/data_frame from a vector or vectors

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a name and a vector

```
my.name <- 'data.values'
my.vec <- 1:5
```

and I'd like to make a tibble/tbl_df/data_frame with one column that has `my.name` as the name of that column and `my.vec` as the values.  What  I have is

```
df <- data_frame(placeholder = rep(NA, length(my.vec)))
df[[my.name]] <- my.vec
df[['placeholder']] <- NULL
```

Which just feels silly.  Is there an easier way to do this?

I am also interested in the case where I have multiple vectors and multiple names, e.g.

```
my.name1 <- 'data.values.day1'
my.name2 <- 'data.values.day2'
my.vec1 <- 1:5
my.vec2 <- 2:6
...
```

Comment: @user5249203 `my.name` will not be evaluated so you end up with a `data.frame` with a column named `my.name`.

Comment: Use a named list, `as_data_frame(setNames(list(my.vec), my.name))`

Comment: Or rename it `data_frame(my.vec) %>% rename(my.name = my.vec)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best answer came in a comment.

DirtySockSniffer recommended:

```
as_data_frame(setNames(list(my.vec), my.name)))
```

which generalizes nicely to the multiple column situation

```
as_data_frame(setNames(list(my.vec1, my.vec2), 
                       c(my.name1, my.name2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `data_frame` first and then set its column names:

```
my.data <- data_frame(my.vec.1, my.vec.2, ...)
names(my.data) <- c(my.name.1, my.name.2, ...) # Order is important here
```